# filtering only one side of a list/iterable in scala

Tags: scala, filter, functional-programming, iterable

I'd like to remove only the *few* last elements of a `List` (or `Seq`), and avoid parsing all elements (and avoid applying the filter function to all of them).

Let's say, for example, I have a random strictly increasing list of values:

```
 import scala.util.Random.nextInt
 val r = (1 to 100).map(_ => nextInt(10)+1).scanLeft(0)(_+_)
```

And I want to remove the elements greater than, say, 300. I can do this like that:

```
r.filter(_<300)
```

but this method parse the whole list. So, is it possible to filter a list only on one end? Something like a `filterRight` method?

subquestions:

- Also, would it be possible for list of values that are not strictly increasing? i.e. remove the elements from the end of a list until one element is, say, below 300.
- if it is not possible for a `List`/`Seq`, what about `IndexedSeq` like `Vector` or `Array`

**Solutions**

I selected @elm solution because it answers the subquestion for general list, not only (strictly) increasing ones.
However, the solution of [@dcastro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32005297/1206998) looks to be more efficient as it doesn't do 2 reverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note [SI-4247](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4247) on *dropWhile but no dropRightWhile*.

Though, a simple implementation that conveys the desired semantics,

```
def dropRightWhile[A](xs: Seq[A], p: A => Boolean) = 
  xs.reverse.dropWhile(p).reverse
```

or equivalently

```
implicit class OpsSeq[A](val xs: Seq[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def dropRightWhile(p: A => Boolean) = xs.reverse.dropWhile(p).reverse
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for something like `dropRightWhile`, which doesn't exist in the standard library ([but has been requested before](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4247)).

I think your best bet is:

```
r.takeWhile(_<300)
```

Since it's an increasing list of values, you can stop performing any checks when you first encounter an element greater than 300